Can I install a 90 degree elbow directly on a shower valve?
I am installing a new shower valve. Can I do a 90degree elbow directly from the valve going down for the water supply? Most installs have pipe going straight out a few inches before turning down.

It is more for ease of working.  The water does not care.

With water pipe there doesn't tend to be code restrictions on the number of bends, etc. Either the flow is adequate for your needs or it isn't, so you have these considerations:

Compatibility: Make sure the thread types match.

Space: Will you be able to spin it on and still operate the valve?

Reliability: Every extra joint you add is a potential leak. Is there a more elegant solution without the extra connection?

Heat from soldering operations: A stub is sometimes used to create a buffer from any sweat joint. Be sure you don't melt your new valve's soft parts. Remove a threaded part and solder in isolation, or install a heat sink of some sort.


